# Can I execute Long data type of java in x32 bit environment?

Tags: java

I really had the thought that Long data type of java which is actually 8bytes=64 bits can even run if tried to execute in a 32bit platform, like windows 32 bit or a processor of x32 architechture?
I am a newbie in Java..So please don't mind my silly question...
Please answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. As per [JLS 17.7. Non-Atomic Treatment of double and long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7) a single operation on a non-volatile 64-bit value like `long` will be represented by two 32-bit operations.

> For the purposes of the Java programming language memory model, a single write to a non-volatile long or double value is treated as two separate writes: one to each 32-bit half. This can result in a situation where a thread sees the first 32 bits of a 64-bit value from one write, and the second 32 bits from another write.
>
> Writes and reads of volatile long and double values are always atomic.
>
> Writes to and reads of references are always atomic, regardless of whether they are implemented as 32-bit or 64-bit values.